# How to allow same keys in one array?

Tags: php

I need to add the same keys to the array, but with different values,

```
foreach ($selections as $selection) {
    $array += [$selection['option_id']=>$selection['product_id']];
}
```

// example output

```
$array = [30=>12,14=>10],
```

but really it should be

```
[30=>7,30=>12,14=>10];
```

When the key repeats, it merges.

Comment: You can't have 2 identical keys in an array so your "should be" example is impossible.

Comment: What you want is not technically possible to begin with. You could store the values as an array under one single key though.

Comment: And `$array[30]` will return what? 7? 12?

Comment: [30=>7,30=>12,14=>10]; ... you can do something like this [30=>7/12,14=>10]; and then explode values with "/" or whatever you like, does this help?

Comment: I think this is a good example of needing to rethink your strategy.  Most of the time, if you cant find a reasonably simple answer, you probably shouldnt be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't.

But you can make the value of this key an array.

So you'll have

```
$array = [30=>[7,12],14=>10];
```

You can use any array functions on $array[30]

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to return the products ids as an array:

```
$array = array_reduce($selections, function ($carry, $selection) {
    if (!isset($carry[$selection['option_id']])) {
        $carry[$selection['option_id']] = [];
    }

    $carry[$selection['option_id']][] = $selection['product_id'];

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Now the result would be:

```
[30 => [7, 12], 14 => [10]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in array are, as the word itself says, keys to access the value they contain and each key must be unique, else you won't have a way to . If you could have two time or more the same value, how could you tell which will access one value and which one will access the other one? To solve your problem you have a way: generate a multidimensional array such that you can have multiple value stored "behind" a single key. E.g. [30 => [7,12],  14 => 10]
Based on your code you can just create a double loop with a nested foreach to navigate through all the value, something like:

```
foreach ($selections as $selection) {
 if(!is_array($selection['product_id'])  $array += [$selection['option_id']=>$selection['product_id']];
 else { 
     foreach ($selection['product_id'] as $product) {
          $array += [$selection['option_id']=> product];
      }
  }
}
```